# Sticky footer does not stay down

Tags: html, css

My footer doesn't stay down when scrolling on my page. Any tips?

CSS of Footer:

```
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  margin: 0;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #399D60;
}
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Can we see your `html`?

Answer (score 0):

Try `position:sticky` or `position:aboslute;`

Answer (score 0):

If you html structure is like bellow:

```
<footer>
    <!-- Your footer content go here -->
</footer>
```

Then your css should be

```
footer {
 /* Your css should go here*/
 /* not .footer, use footer */
}
```

Or you can give it a class `footer` so you can target with `.footer`

```
<footer class="footer">
    <!-- Your footer content go here -->
</footer>
```

And now you can target it using class selector such as `.footer`

Answer (score 0):

I actually wrote up an article on how to make simple responsive sticky footers that work on all screen sizes. No positioning required. You can read about how it works or just copy the code to make it work for you.

[Responsive Sticky Footer Without Positioning](https://ceckenrode.github.io/responsive-sticky-footer-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

Yours footer does **not** stay down because you set:  `position: fixed;`

**Try this:** `position:relative;`